# commercetools: Is there any class in JVM SDK to generate OAuth2 token?

Tags: commercetools

In the commercetools JVM SDK class [SphereClient](http://sphereio.github.io/sphere-jvm-sdk/javadoc/master/io/sphere/sdk/client/SphereClient.html) is no way to access the access token of the client, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible, buy you can use the class [TokensFacade](http://sphereio.github.io/sphere-jvm-sdk/javadoc/master/io/sphere/sdk/client/TokensFacade.html) to obtain another, fresh generated, access token.